# Sum of aggregations does not get last value

Tags: birt

I am building a report in wich I have a nested table with some values, and an agregation of this values.

so if my report gets 3 main results, I will have 3 nested tables with an aggregation value for each table.

At the main table's footer I have a field to display the sum of all the aggregations. I make the sum in the nested tables onCreate event like this `sum = sum + row["Aggregation"];`

It works fine except by the fact that it always ignores the last nested table aggregation, why is that ??

I tried using other events in the nested table but none worked.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]